# Avoiding full Table scan in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query which fetches the last 30 rows from the whole table which contains thousands of entries.The table is large so database query is taking more than 5 minutes to execute. How can I avoid the full table scan on the table so that it scans only the last few rows. I am using Oracle 11g

```
SELECT DD,MODEL,CNT,SYS
  FROM DVCE_TAB
  WHERE DD >= TO_DATE('2015-08-09','YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND DD <= TO_DATE('2015-09-08','YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND SYS IN ('00','01')
```

DD is the date and SYS is System type of device and MODEL is name of device
DD and MODEL is the combined primary key for the Table
TABLE contains thousands of entries and has data from 2010
I have to just fetch last months data

Comment: What is your SQL query?

Comment: SELECT DD,COL2,COL3 FROM TABLE WHERE DD >= '2015-08-09' AND <= '2015-09-08' AND SYS IN ('00','01')

TABLE contains thousands of entries and has data from 2010 I have to just fetch last months data

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definition of the columns in `DVCE_TAB`, along with any indexes which are defined on `DVCE_TAB`. Thanks.

Comment: Millions of rows are not a problem in a well designed DB.  Add an index on your table including columns DD and SYS in your index

Comment: @PavelGatnar - he's fixed that now.

Comment: Add index on your table and change your where condition for someting like dd >= TO_DATE('2015-08-09','YYYY-MM-DD') AND SYS IN ('00','01'). It should help.

Comment: Even after adding that condition the query planner is doing a index range scan which is taking the same time as full scan

Comment: @JoSav You're correct about the indeces, but his where clauses is SARGable as is.

Comment: Have you updated the table statistics?

Comment: Yes I have updated table statistics

Comment: You can face low memory/disc space too...

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas come to mind:

1) Define an index on the DD and SYS columns:

```
CREATE INDEX DVCE_TAB_1
  ON DVCE_TAB (DD, SYS);
```

You'll probably need to gather table statistics after adding indexes:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(ownname => 'YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME',
                                tabname => 'DVCE_TAB');
END;
```

That may be all you need, but if needed you can always...

2) Partition DVCE_TAB on the DD column.

```
CREATE TABLE DVCE_TAB
  (...column definitions...)
  PARTITION BY RANGE (DD) 
    INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))
  PARTITION DVCE_TAB_P1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-01-2000', 'DD-MM-YYYY')));
```

To do this you may need to actually create a new table with a different name, copy all the existing data from the 'old' DVCE_TAB to the 'new' DVCE_TAB, then drop the original table and rename the 'new' table to `DVCE_TAB`.

Best of luck.